# Concordance test and corresponding plot

Tags: statistical-significance, agreement-statistics, cohens-d

I have a list of genes identified using algorithm_A, then using algorithm_B and finally  using algorithm_C; then a second list of genes identified using algorithm_A, then using algorithm_B and then algorithm_C, and so on for a total of 100 gene lists.

To compare the overlap of the identified gene list using the three methods, I used the Cohen test for each gene lists. I would like to know first if it is the best choice and second how can I graphically plot the Cohen test results for the 100 gene lists.